# How to create a matrix in OCaml?

Tags: arrays, matrix, ocaml

I'am learning OCaml and currently i'am trying to undertand how iteration works in OCaml and how to create a matrix. I want an array 5 x 5 filled with 0. I know there is an issue with shared references so i created a new array at each iteration however iam having issues in other places, specifically at line 6. Let me know of other issues like indentation practices.

```
open Array;;

let n = ref 5 and i = ref 0 in 
let m = Array.make !n 0 in 
while !i < !n do
    m.(!i) <- Array.make !n 0;;
    i := !i + 1;;
done

m;;
```

Comment: HI @power_output, SO is not a code factory... You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: I learned a lot in Java and C just by searching Google which many times lead to SO but now i'am having problems with this language. I learn best with examples but i dont see any with this language. I've been looking at this code changing things for quite some time but i can't seem to figure out what's wrong that's why i came here hoping someone could give a helping hand.

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: line 6, characters 27-29:Error:Syntax error

Comment: @power-output nothing else?

Comment: No. It's strange, maybe it won't even try the rest after a Syntax error?

Answer (score 9):

You are using `;;` too much. Contrary to popular belief, `;;` is not part of ordinary OCaml syntax (in my opinion anyway). It's just a special way to tell the toplevel (the REPL) that you want it to evaluate what you've typed so far.

Leave the `;;` after `open Array`. But change all but the last `;;` to `;` instead.

(Since you reference the `Array` module by name in your code, which IMHO is good style, you can also just leave out the `open Array;;` altogether.)

You want the last `;;` because you do want the toplevel to evaluate what you've typed so far.

Your syntax error is caused by the fact that your overall code is like this

```
let ... in
let ... in
while ... do
    ...
done

m
```

The `while` is one expression (in OCaml everything is an expression) and `m` is another expression. If you want to have two expressions in a row you need `;` between them. So you need `;` after `done`.

You also have a type error. When you create `m` you're creating an array of ints (your given initial value is 0). So you can't make it into a matrix (an array of arrays) later in the code.

Also (not trying to overload you with criticisms :-) this code reads like imperative code. It's not particularly idiomatic OCaml code. In most people's code, using `ref` is pretty rare. One immediate improvement I see would just be to say `let n = 5`. You're not changing the value of `n` anywhere that I see (though maybe this is part of a larger chunk of code). Another improvement would be to use `for` instead of `while`.

Finally, you can do this entire operation in one function call:

```
let n = 5 in
let m = Array.init n (fun i -> Array.make n 0) in
m
```

Using explicit loops is actually also quite rare in OCaml (at least in my code).

Or you could try this:

```
let n = 5 in
let m = Array.make_matrix n n 0 in
m
```

Comment: Why do you use the anonymous function with i as argument if that i is not used?

Comment: To show you that it corresponds somewhat to `i` in your code.